# Mesh Collider of URDF robot not working when parented to an image target

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I am working to make an URDF robotic arm interact with other objects in the scene on Unity 2020.3. With the newest version of Vuforia Engine installed, the URDF arm that is parented to an image target, alongside with other objects, all with its corresponding colliders and articulation body/rigid body component applied, should appear in the AR environment (I am using an Android device). While the URDF arm can collide with other objects in play mode inside Unity, when the image target is implemented, the arm would simply pass through the object.

I made sure that all the visual and collision components are correctly configurated in Unity, in which the collision would appear normal without Image Target component, even if Vuforia Engine is initiated. Weird to me. I am new to Unity and Vuforia, please help me out.

Comment: Probably not your main problem but the latest Vuforia Engine only supports Unity versions newer than 2021.3 as described here https://library.vuforia.com/platform-support/supported-versions

Comment: Ya, just tried the version switch, did not work, same problem exist. Thanks though!!